# Switching between batteries while charging

Tags: mosfet, switches, battery-charging, charging

Let's say I have a 4 A current source and two 12 V car batteries, connected in series (with a tap in the middle).

What in your opinion is the simplest MOSFET switching circuit, that would allow me to choose  1 of these 4 charging configurations?

1. No charging
2. Charging the "upper" battery only
3. Charging the "lower" battery only
4. Charging both batteries

I also need to be able to measure battery voltages all the time. I thought about H-bridge, but can't figure out proper connections.

Comment: A lead-acid battery cannot reliably be charged from a high current source. Desulfated, yes, quick-charged, yes, but not continuously. This is because as the cells approach fully charged, they stop drawing current. If driven from a current source, the voltage increases beyond the "gassing" voltage of the cells (constant current), and the water in the electrolyte is electrolyzed away.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. It's not actually a current source, but a ~30 V DC voltage source with current limit @4A. The current drops when the batteries are getting more and more charged.

Comment: Why not just use the 30V source to charge them both in series? And if not, how do you propose dropping the excess voltage from 30V to the 14V or 15V you need to charge just one? That would need dissipating around 60W somewhere - not really too efficient.

Comment: Would you consider using relays instead of MOSFET's? Also, can you please advise whether any of the battery terminals are grounded, and whether your charger is fully isolated? You could run into some serious problems if your charger negative and your lower battery negative are both earth grounded, or could become earth grounded.

Comment: The charger circuit is powered from power transformer and it draws power from mains - it's pretty flexible - when the output voltage drops, the current drawn from mains also drops, so the output power is adapted to the load. I'd prefer not to use relays, I'd rather like to use FETs, if it's possible. The "lower" battery negative terminal, as well as the ground of the charger, are connected to common ground, but not to the mains earth connection.

Charging two batteries connected in series causes voltage differences between them - I want to do some kind of active balancing by "smart" charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery) explains the proper way to charge lead-acid batteries. To reliably charge two (12V) car batteries, which are wired in series (24V), states that each battery should have it's own charger.

The reason why is that if battery `A` is more charged than battery `B`, it will draw less current. Current and Voltage are inverse to each other (ignoring resistance) so if one decreases, the other must increase. Battery `A` draws less current, so the voltage across it must increase. And we get the same issue as previous where the voltage across battery `A` is too high, and the electrolyte starts boiling away. Lead-acid batteries in series are a naturally *unbalanced* system, and will drift towards this condition over time.

Now it may be possible to "over-charge" two series lead-acid batteries to balance them, such as with a 30v supply like you envision. However, depending on the imbalance, one will almost certainly have too high a voltage across it, and begin electrolyzing the water into \$H_2\$ and \$O_2\$ gas, lowering the cell levels. Adding fresh (distilled) water to compensate will work for awhile, but the process is degrading to that battery, so isn't a viable long-term solution.

As for switching a 30V/4A-limited DC supply to a 24v/12V battery array via MOSFETs, this sounds technically possible, but dangerous due to the issues @mkeith raises.

What can't reliably be done:

- Charging two 12V batteries in series (24V) from 30V indefinitely.
- Charging any combination of these from a 30V constant-voltage (CV) supply.
- Charging a 12V battery from a 30V supply directly.

Even if a power supply says "4A current limited", it is still a Constant Voltage supply. Meaning it will continuously *try* to push 30V into whatever is connected to it, regardless of what the current is. So if it were connected to a discharged 12V battery, 18v, 20v, even 30v may initially appear across it (and the electrolyte starts boiling away...)

Also note that voltage measurement is not very accurate for State Of Charge (SOC) indication of lead-acid batteries. For instance, a fully-charged 12V battery should read 13.2V the instant it comes off the charger. An hour later, it may read 12.5V, even though very little charge has actually been lost. Under heavy load, the battery voltage may read 10V. Removing the load, it may read 10.5V initially, then 11V after an hour, then 12v after six hours. If one cell in a battery fails, it may permanently report a lower voltage, leading the operator to believe it needs more charging, when in fact this won't help. And the reported voltage also changes with temperature.

I'd suggest using the 30v DC, 4A "CV" supply as a front-end for two purpose-built 13v/4A chargers. I.e., implement two [isolated buck regulators (snva674b.pdf)](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva674b/snva674b.pdf) (2x 30v/2A to 13v/4A) or similar.

The reason I chose 13.0v constant-voltage is that there is almost zero risk of overcharging at this voltage, and the charger can remain on indefinitely. Down-side is, the battery will never be 100% charged, always slightly less than this, and it may take a long time to charge. But it is inherently safe and simple (remember to use fuses and any other protection devices as needed.)

But of course there are many other factors to consider when charging batteries, and TI has created a nice [writeup on DC-DC charging (slyp089.pdf)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slyp089/slyp089.pdf) which is a bit technical but spot-on.

So if you have a good amount of skill and experience in electronic circuit design, you could try something like this. If you'd rather not muck with it, then the easiest solution is to just use two mains-powered 12v battery chargers and charge each one separately. (Note, some of these are "isolated" and will work fine together, but I wouldn't be surprised if some are *not isolated*, and connecting them results in an explosion. Read the fine print!) Always use fuses around a battery which can deliver 1000 Amperes of current and explode from sparks and gaseous hydrogen.